# Where to get gradle aar for Google Ads?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm attempting to update a Unity game to use a newer version of Google Services Ads.  We currently have `play-services-ads-9.0.1.aar` included in the game assets. But we'd really like to update it to a new version like `15.0.1`. I know in Android I can just add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1` to my gradle file and it'll pull the aar in automatically.

Is there an easy way I can just download that aar so I can replace it in my Unity assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 15.0.0.:

https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/15.0.0/play-services-ads-15.0.0.aar

I've found it on [THIS](https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-play-services-ads) site, but I'm afraid that replacing one library might not work... Instead of that maybe just update your [Mobile Ads Unity plugin](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start)?

Comment: Well this gets me what I need. But I'll do some vetting to see what we should be doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should never manually download & add these libraries!

Cons: These libraries have their own other dependency & downloading each & every one will be a great pain!

Instead, simply add the dependency in gradle & it'll do the rest.

Comment: Is there a way to use gradle within Unity? I know you can in Android but we're developing in Unity.